# Ag-Grid Aggregation of string and display the Sum Value on the Column

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to display the ag-grid table with sum value in the each level of row grouping.

```
 columnDefs = [
    { headerName:"Subject", field: "subject", rowGroup: true },
    { headerName:"Grade", field: "grade", rowGroup: true },
    { headerName:"Emp Id", field: "empId" },
    { headerName:"Score", field: "score",  aggFunc: "sum"}
   ];


rowData = [
   {subject: "Maths", grade: "A", empId:"1", score: "80"},
   {subject: "Maths", grade: "A", empId:"2", score: "70"},
   {subject: "Maths", grade: "A", empId:"3", score: "90"},
   {subject: "Maths", grade: "A", empId:"4", score: "100"}
 ]
```

Here I want to calculate the Score value and display in the each level of row group in the tale column. but the `aggFunc: "sum"` not working because the `"score"` property is a **string type**.

Is there any possibility to calculate the sore value and display it in the table

Comment: convert you rowdata "score" value to number... aggregation works on numbers not on strings.

Answer (score 2):

define a custom aggregation function of yours and use it in column definition

```
columnDefs = [
    { headerName:"Subject", field: "subject", rowGroup: true },
    { headerName:"Grade", field: "grade", rowGroup: true },
    { headerName:"Emp Id", field: "empId" },
    { headerName:"Score", field: "score",  aggFunc: myCustomSumFunction}
   ];

function myCustomSumFunction(values) {
    var sum = 0;
    values.forEach( function(value) {sum += Number(value);} );
    return sum;
}
rowData = [
   {subject: "Maths", grade: "A", empId:"1", score: "80"},
   {subject: "Maths", grade: "A", empId:"2", score: "70"},
   {subject: "Maths", grade: "A", empId:"3", score: "90"},
   {subject: "Maths", grade: "A", empId:"4", score: "100"}
 ]
```

here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GxdR9nDUeuluxSew)

Answer (score 0):

```
columnDefs = [
    { headerName:"Subject", field: "subject", rowGroup: true },
    { headerName:"Grade", field: "grade", rowGroup: true },
    { headerName:"Emp Id", field: "empId" },
    { headerName:"Score", field: "score", aggFunc: "sum", valueGetter: params => parseInt(params.data.score),
    }
   ];
```